# jQuery filtering with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, function, filter

I need some help here, I spent 1 day but still could not make it..

```
<div data-src-object="1" data-src-color="blue" data-src-color="green">Product1</div>
<div data-src-object="2" data-src-color="blue" data-src-color="red">Product2</div>
<div data-src-object="3" data-src-color="green">Product3</div>

<div id="filter">
<span class="label label-info" value="blue">Blue</span>
<span class="label label-default" value="red">Red</span>
<span class="label label-default" value="green">Green</span>
</div>


$('div[data-src-object]').filter(function(){ 
return (   )
}).hide();
```

"show only an object that its data-src-color exists as a value in .label-info, the rest hide"

In this example only product1 and product 2 will be visible

The closest I thought was:

$(this).attr('data-src-color')!=$('#filter .label-info').val()

alert($(this).attr('data-src-color'))

But with the alert I noticed that was showing only the first color of every object

Comment: Product3 should also be displayed isn't it? It has data-src-color `green` and there is `label-default` with `green`

Comment: you can't have `data-src-color` multiple times on the same object i believe

Comment: Thank you Eddie!!! Yes Carsten you are right. No Ankit, the filtering was from the span(buttons). I just wanted them to be clicked-change color and then the products be filtered. Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to have the `data-src-color` on a comma separated value.

```js
//Get all values of elements with class label-info
let val = $(".label-info").map(function() {return $(this).attr('value')}).get();

//Select all data-src-object and show all
//Filter the data
//Hide data-src-object with no color on val variable
$('div[data-src-object]').show().filter(function() {
  let data = $(this).data('src-color').split(',') //Get the src-color data and split to form an array
  return !$(data).filter(val).length;             //If 2 arrays dont have a common value, return as true
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-src-object="1" data-src-color="blue,green">Product1</div>
<div data-src-object="2" data-src-color="blue,red">Product2</div>
<div data-src-object="3" data-src-color="green">Product3</div>

<div id="filter">
  <span class="label label-info" value="blue">Blue</span>
  <span class="label label-default" value="red">Red</span>
  <span class="label label-default" value="green">Green</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user/sasawant1977/fiddles/)

HTML

```
   <select id="filter">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<div class="color-div" data-src-object="1" data-src-color="blue green">Product1</div>
<div class="color-div" data-src-object="2" data-src-color="blue" data-src-color="red">Product2</div>
<div class="color-div" data-src-object="3" data-src-color="green">Product3</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").on('change', function(){
    var selectedColor = $(this).val();
    $("div.color-div").each(function(index){
        if($(this).attr("data-src-color").indexOf(selectedColor) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  });

  $("#filter").change();
});
```